# How to plot the hazard function from survival data?

Tags: r, cox-regression, hazard

**Goal**

I am trying to plot the hazard function of survival data in R.

**Attempt**

I am using the NCCTG lung cancer dataset in the `survival` package in R.

In my understanding the hazard function has the following form:

```
h(t) = h0(t) * e^(b1 * x1 + ... + bn * xn)
```

The values for x1, ..., xn are independent variables derived from the data self and with the following code, I am able to obtain the values for coefficients b1, ..., bn.

```
# Sample code
library(survival)

lung$status <- lung$status - 1
coxph_mdl <- coxph( Surv(time, status ) ~ age, data = lung )
summary(coxph_mdl)
```

**Question**

How do I plot the hazard function of a cohort of patients with survival data in R?

Comment: See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25317/how-to-calculate-predicted-hazard-rates-from-a-cox-ph-model

Comment: Thanks for the response! I stumbled upon the `basehaz` function indeed, but noticed that it provides cumulative hazards instead of the hazard function... am I correct?